# Submit Form with Input still selected

Tags: jquery, forms, focus, submit

I have this simple form for which I am attempting to submit.  It has 3 input:text fields which are populated with data from a calculation depending on which field you are entering information in.  I can hit enter and it works fine because I am still focused in the field but the form won't submit if I hit the submit button.  Here is the html.

```
<form id="pr">
<table width="680px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="header">Pressure Conversion Calculator</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#efefef" class="text">Psi</td>
    <td bgcolor="#efefef" class="text">MPa</td>
    <td bgcolor="#efefef" class="text">Bar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#efefef" class="text"><input id="psi" name="psi" type="text"  size="7" value=""/></td>
    <td bgcolor="#efefef" class="text"><input id="mpa" name="mpa" type="text"  size="7" value="" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="#efefef" class="text"><input id="bar" name="bar" type="text"  size="7" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#efefef">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#efefef">
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="submit" value="Calculate" class="submitbutton"/> 
    <input type="button" name="clear" id="clear" value="Clear Fields" class="submitbutton"/>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#efefef" height="5"></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

and then the jquery

```
$('#submit').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();

    if($('#psi').is(':focus')){
        pressure = parseInt($('#psi').val());       
        bar = pressure * 0.0690;
        $('#bar').val(bar.toFixed());       
        mpa = pressure * 0.006894759086775369;
        $('#mpa').val(mpa.toFixed());               
    }

    else if($('#mpa').is(':focus')){
        pressure = parseInt($('#mpa').val());
        bar = pressure * 10;
        $('#bar').val(bar.toFixed());        
        psi = pressure * 145.0377;
        psi = Math.round(psi/1000)*1000;    
        $('#psi').val(psi);             
    }

     else if($('#bar').is(':focus')){
        pressure = parseInt($('#bar').val());
        mpa = pressure * 0.1;
        $('#mpa').val(mpa.toFixed());
        psi = pressure * 14.500;
        psi = Math.round(psi/1000)*1000;
        $('#psi').val(psi);     
    }

    else{}  

});
```

I am kind of new to this and am just trying to work out all of the bugs.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` prevents it from submitting, since that's the default action of clicking on the submit button. You should only do that when the validation determines that it shouldn't submit.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular button (remove `type="submit"`), then submit the form in your code:

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```

Comment: This doesn't work because if you focus into another field and type in a number there it reverts to the original answer in the text fields provided from the previous submit.